# Setting state with async/await in React

Tags: reactjs, promise, async-await, react-native, es6-promise

In the code example I am trying to call `setState()` with an array of `Promise` objects. The data (coordinates) have to be fetched from an external REST service.

Is there a common pattern for doing this in React?

```
   async getLocations(locations) {
     var annotations = locations.map(this.getLocation);
     console.log("ANNOTATIONS:", annotations);
     this.setState({
       annotations:annotations
     });
   }

   async getLocation(location) {
      try {
        let res = await Geocoder.geocodeAddress(location.address);
        return (
          {
              latitude: res[0].position.lat,
              longitude: res[0].position.lng,
              title: location.address,
              subtitle: location.provider,
          }
        );
      }
      catch(err) {
        console.log("Error fetching geodata",err);
      }
      return null;
  }
```

The resulting array contains Promise objects and the state update results in error:

```
ANNOTATIONS: [Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise]
ExceptionsManager.js:70 Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop `annotations[0].latitude` was not specified in `MapView`.
    in MapView (at index.js:204)
    in SampleAppInspection (at renderApplication.ios.js:90)
    in RCTView (at View.js:348)
    in View (at renderApplication.ios.js:65)
    in RCTView (at View.js:348)
    in View (at renderApplication.ios.js:64)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.ios.js:89)
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Answer (score 2):

This is actually pretty simple. You need to unwrap the array of promises you're passing `setState` since it is not promise aware:

```
 this.setState({
   annotations: await Promise.all(annotations)
 });
```

The `Promise.all` part waits for the entire array and the await unwraps it for `setState`.